# Python Win32 - equivalent function to DriveInfo.IsReady

Tags: python, winapi

I'm trying to find an equivalent Python function to the Windows function [DriveInfo.IsReady](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.isready.aspx).  I've spent a while searching through the functions provided by win32api and win32file but I can't find anything (though perhaps that's because I didn't manage to find much useful documentation online, so was simply searching through the listing of functions).

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used `GetVolumeInformation` in the past to determine this.  For example, something like:

```
def is_drive_ready(drive_name):
    try:
        win32api.GetVolumeInformation(drive_name)
        return True
    except:
        return False

print 'ready:', is_drive_ready('c:\\') # true
print 'ready:', is_drive_ready('d:\\') # false (on my system)
```

You'll need the [win32api](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) module.